# How to display two expression result in different column in oracle sql

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I have a table `ACCOUNT(ACCOUNT_NUMBER,BRANCH_NAME,BALANCE)`

Now I need to find in Oracle SQL : all accounts with balances over R.100000 receive 6 percent interest whereas all others receive 5 percent.

I need to display the balance with 6% and balance with 5% in two different column.

What is the SQL query for it?

Comment: sounds like homework.  what have u tried?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Make an attempt and come back here with specific questions. "Write my code for me" is not an acceptable question.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this is what you want:

```
select 
  account_number, 
  case 
    when balance > 100000 then balance*1.06 
  end AS With6PercentInterest,
  case 
    when balance <= 100000 then balance*1.05
  end AS With5PercentInterest
from ACCOUNT;
```

[Sample SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/56fa7/1)